# How to place a default file name in the file dialog asksaveasfile python

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to place a value in the file dialog by default when the user is saving a file. Anyone can advise the syntax of it ?

```
saveFilePath = fileDialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', title="Save the file", defaultextension=".txt")
```

For example: NewFile should be filled in when the file dialog is open

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
initialfile
```

as proposed by Bryan Oakley worked.

Example:

```
saveFilePath  =  filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialfile = "INSERT DEFAULT FILE NAME HERE",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
```

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is to use: intialfile = 'default_file_name'  in your saveFilePath. Below is a Python 3 block you can use to read a dataframe from CSV and "Save As" using tkinter.

```
    def ExportApplications():
        #reads the file to dataframe
        df_testFile = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

        #creates SaveAs dialogue and prompts user to save
        #you can enter multiple file type formats in data FYI
        data = [('csv', '*.csv')]
        file_out = asksaveasfile(filetypes=data, defaultextension=data,initialfile = "This_is_the_default_file_name_when_saving")

        #writes output to location specified by user in "Save As" dialogue
        df_testFile.to_csv(file_out, index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the below:

```
saveFilePath  =  filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "/<file_name>",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
```

https://pythonspot.com/tk-file-dialogs/

Comment: `initialdir` is only for the directory. For the file name itself you need to use `initialfile`. Also, the OP used `asksaveasfile` but your example uses `asksaveasfilename` which might be confusing to people who are just starting to learn tkinter.

Comment: hey bryan do you know a method to do this as the above method just shows up a search results directory with login searched in it for some reason always